# Leaf to Root Path Java

Tags: java, arraylist, tree

I have been searching around but can't seem to understand how to return path from leaf to root.

For Example:

```
         A
       /   \
      B     C
     /     / \ 
    D     E   F
```

So if I do `A.find(E)` it should return `[A,C,E]` and if I do `B.find(D)` it should return `[B,D]`

My attempt :

```
// Base Case - The root of this Tree is c. Route is just [child]
public List<Person> find(Person c) {
    List<Person> path = new ArrayList<Person>();
    Person p = c;
    while(c != null) {
        path.add(p);
    }
    return path;
}
```

Comment: If you want to get to the root you need: while (node.parent != null) {node = node.parent} thats it

Comment: This question is a bit unclear: you ask `I... can't seem to understand how to return path from leaf to root.`, but then you say the `find()` implementation should return the path from a leaf to a lower leaf. I'm confused on whether you're trying to find elements in both directions, or only children like the examples indicate.

Comment: Like the example. find() is just a name I called it could be anything.

Comment: Could you tell me more about the `Person` class? Unless the Person class has Person elements exposed in some way, one cannot navigate a tree just from a Person. Instead, there has to be a another tree predefined holding people. So is Person a tree root itself, or are you traversing another tree? Either way, could you make the example a bit more robust. (Recommended reading: [mcve])

Comment: Or are you asking how to implement a tree with a find method in Java?

Comment: Your "attempt" is obviously bogus, since `while(c != null) { path.add(p); }` is a never-ending loop (unless `c` is *initially* null), given that `c` isn't updated in the loop. Also, since the method is supposed to "find" a descendant node, and you say "Route is just [child]" (which we can presume should be named `children`, i.e. plural), perhaps the code should somehow use it, don't you think? Please provide a *better* "attempt".

Comment: I know. That's why I'm on here to ask how to do it properly because I couldn't understand it. If I already know how then why would I even bother asking the question.

Comment: We can only help you if we understand what you're asking. I've tried my best to get more information about what you're trying to do, but you haven't answered my most recent question. If you don't understand the concepts you're asking about well enough to ask a focused question, you should probably go back and study whatever parts you don't understand.

Comment: Oh, about your question on Person class. It's couple hundred lines so I didn't want to post that. I got the general idea answered from Hearen so my problem is solved. But thanks for helping Graham.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for your question: searching from **any** start node to the specified **target** node in the tree:

```
public class PathFind {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Node dNode = new Node("D", null, null);
        Node bNode = new Node("B", dNode, null);

        Node eNode = new Node("E");
        Node fNode = new Node("F");
        Node cNode = new Node("C", eNode, fNode);

        Node aNode = new Node("A", bNode, cNode);

        System.out.println(aNode.find(null));
        System.out.println(aNode.find(bNode));
        System.out.println(aNode.find(cNode));
        System.out.println(aNode.find(eNode));
        System.out.println(bNode.find(dNode));

        System.out.println(bNode.find(eNode));
        System.out.println(cNode.find(dNode));
    }


    static class Node {
        Node left, right;
        String val;

        public Node(String theVal, Node theLeft, Node theRight) {
            this.val = theVal;
            this.left = theLeft;
            this.right = theRight;
        }

        public Node(String theVal) {
            this(theVal, null, null);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return val;
        }

        public List<Node> find(Node theNode) {
            List<Node> path = new ArrayList<>();
            if (find(this, theNode, path)) return path;
            else return null;
        }



        // 

        /**
         * 
         * @param startNode start from the startNode to search;
         * @param theNode the node to search;
         * @param path using a list to record the path along the way;
         * @return to indicate whether there is a path or not;
         */
        private boolean find(Node startNode, Node theNode, List<Node> path) {
            path.add(startNode);
            if (startNode == theNode) return true; 
            if (startNode == null) return false;
            if (find(startNode.left, theNode, path)) return true;
            else path.remove(path.size() - 1); // remove the last for the right search;
            if (find(startNode.right, theNode, path)) return true;
            else path.remove(path.size() - 1);
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

There are three cases covered to ensure it will meet the requirement:

1. you can start from any node to any node in the tree;
2. the pre-order first path will be returned if the target node is `null`;
3. if there is no such path, the `path` will be `null` to indicate there is **NO** such path;

The output for the demo provided above:

```
[A, B, D, null]
[A, B]
[A, C]
[A, C, E]
[B, D]
null
null
```